# DataStudio returns random error id when using custom connector

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am using script.google.com to create a custom connector that can read CSV data from drive.google.com and send the data to Googles data studio.

When running the connector and inserting a simple table inside the data studio, I receive a simple that the request could not be processed because of an server error. The error id is changing every time I "re-publish" the script.

This is

```
function getData(request) {

  var dataSchema = [];

  request.fields.forEach(function(field) {
    for (var i = 0; i < csvDataSchema.length; i++) {
      if (csvDataSchema[i].name === field.name) {
        dataSchema.push(csvDataSchema[i]);
        break;
      }
    }
  });

  csvFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + request.configParams.documentId);
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile);

  var data = [];

  csvData.forEach(function(row) {
    data.push({
      values: row
    });
  });


  console.log(  {
    schema: dataSchema,
    rows: data
  } );

  return {
    schema: dataSchema,
    rows: data
  };
};
```

This is the csvDataSchema:

```
var csvDataSchema = [
  {
    name: 'date',
    label: 'Date',
    dataType: 'STRING',
    semantics: {
      conceptType: 'DIMENSION'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'nanoseconds',
    label: 'nanoseconds',
    dataType: 'NUMBER',
    semantics: {
      "isReaggregatable": true,
      conceptType: 'METRIC'
    }
  },{
    name: 'size',
    label: 'Size of Testfile in MByte',
    dataType: 'STRING',
    semantics: {
      "isReaggregatable": false,
      conceptType: 'DIMENSION'
  }

  }
];
```

And this is the result of the getData function, stringified:

```
{"schema":[{"name":"date","label":"Date","dataType":"STRING","semantics":{"conceptType":"DIMENSION"}},{"name":"size","label":"Size of Testfile in MByte","dataType":"STRING","semantics":{"isReaggregatable":false,"conceptType":"DIMENSION"}}],"rows":[{"values":["2017-05-23",123,"1"]},{"values":["2017-05-23",123,"1"]}]}
```

It perfectly fits [to the reference](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getdata). I am providing more information, but following the tutorial it should work, anyways.

Those are the fields provided in *request*:

[image]

And this is what getDate *returns*:

[image]

So, what I am wondering first is: Why is there a random error id? And what could be wrong with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only return fields/columns included in `request`. Currently, `data` contains all fields that are in `csvFile`. Depending on your chart element in your dashboard, `request` will most likely contain only a subset of your full schema. See [example implementation at the Data Studio Open Source repo](https://github.com/google/datastudio/blob/master/community-connectors/stackoverflow-questions/main.js#L397).

If this does not solve the problem, you should setup [error handing](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/error-handling) and check if the error is occurring at any specific line.

Comment: From my point of view the result fits the request-schema. I added a more detailed info in my question. Furthermore it's pretty clear that the error occurs when returning the result, I am logging to the console before that line.

But I will check with the example implementation, maybe this leads to the error I am doing.

Comment: Thanks for posting the additional info. This actually clears the confusion - your `getData()` request contains only `date` and `size`. This is reflected in the schema returned through `getData()`. However, `rows` contain values for all three fields. If you filter and pass back only the requested fields **in order**, that should solve the problem. The example I mentioned in the answer should be helpful in doing this.

Comment: This leads to the solution, I understand what you are saying. After adding the third column in DataStudio, the error disappeared. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad it worked out! Feel free to contribute your code to [Data Studio's Open Source repo](https://github.com/google/datastudio) so other users can benefit from it!

Comment: I surely will, need to clean it up and document it before.

Answer (score 0):

@Minhaz Kazi gave the missing hint:

As I did not  "dynamically" filled the response object in getData, I always returned all three columns.

With my code above the only thing I had to do is adding the third column as a dimension or a metric.

So I changed my code to dynamically return the columns so it will fit to the response. For this I had to implement an function that will transform the CSV-data into an object.

This is the getData() function now:

```
  function getData(request) {

  var url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="
  + request.configParams.documentId;

  var csvFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile);

  var sourceData = csvToObject(csvData);

  var data = [];

  sourceData.forEach(function(row) {
    var values = [];
    dataSchema.forEach(function(field) {
      switch(field.name) {
        case 'date':
          values.push(row.date);
          break;
        case 'nanoseconds':
          values.push(row.nanoseconds);
          break;
        case 'size':
          values.push(row.size);
          break;
        default:
          values.push('');
      }
    });
    data.push({
      values: values
    });
  });

  return {
    schema: dataSchema,
    rows: data
  };

};}
```

And this is the function to convert the CSV data to an object:

```
 function csvToObject(array) {
    var headers = array[0];

  var jsonData = [];
    for ( var i = 1, length = array.length; i < length; i++ )
    {
      var row = array[i];
      var data = {};
      for ( var x = 0; x < row.length; x++ )
      {
        data[headers[x]] = row[x];
      }
      jsonData.push(data);

    }

    return jsonData;
  }
```

(it's based on a so-solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786995/create-object-on-the-fly-from-csv), I modified it to fit my source CSV data)